# Editing default fields' help_text for form in Django (1.11)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-users

For the past couple days I have been trying to solve a strange problem with the default `help_text` on a form I created to handle user signups. I first noticed the issue when I saw that the html django is inserting as the default `help_text` is getting escaped.

[Screenshot of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBjiE.png)

Instead of displaying the `<ul>`, which I remind you is the default `help_text` that django includes for password fields, it is displaying plain text.

So this is where I first noticed that must be doing something wrong. If the default form `help_text` is getting escaped and looking awful like that, I'm clearly making a mistake. Next I will explain what I did to try to fix this, and then will give a overview of the `model`, `form`, `view`, and `template` so you guys have something to work from.

The first solution I found online was to use the `Meta` class, so I did in my `forms.py` under the `class SignUpForm:` that I am modifying.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User    

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
        company = forms.CharField()
        city = forms.CharField()
        state = forms.CharField()
        zip = forms.IntegerField()
        address = forms.CharField()
        phone = forms.IntegerField()

        class Meta:
            model = User
            # help_text = mark_safe
            fields = ('company', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'address', 'phone', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
            labels = {
                'state': 'US States',
                'password1': 'passcode1',
                'password2': 'passcode2',
                'username': 'human person',
                'email': 'telegraph',
                'city': 'locality',
                'phone': "tele",
            }
            help_texts = {
                'password1': 'Something that doesnt look awful',
                'password2': 'Something else',
                'username': 'Please enter an appropriate human name.',
                'email': 'Which office?',
                'city': 'What county?',
                'phone': 'Please Include Country Code',
            }
```

This is where I started to realize the problem was bigger than I thought. Not only is something causing a `help_text` to be escaped, some of these fields accept my changes while others don't. The custom fields that I have extended the default `UserCreationForm` with (in this example `city` and `phone` don't display their new `label` or `help_text`, while the default fields `username` and `email` both display their inane new `label` and `help_text`. And to top it all off the `password1` and `password2` fields remain unchanged.

[Screenshot of class Meta result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l40U3.png)

Alright, so that didn't work. What about hardcoding it right into the form? Well it turns out that mostly works, but it introduces another level of complication for me in this example, as well as feeling like bad practices. I'll explain.

Since my form is extending the default django `UserCreationForm` I don't actually setup the fields in my `SignUpForm`, they are added automatically and I use their fields in the `class Meta:` So in order to hardcode my way around this problem I have to add them.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(help_text=mark_safe("Please enter an appropriate human name."), label='human name')
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput, help_text=mark_safe('Which office?'), label='telegraph')
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, help_text=mark_safe('Something that doesnt look awful'),
                                label='Passcode')
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, help_text=mark_safe('Something else'), label='Passcode 2')
    company = forms.CharField(help_text=mark_safe("Please enter a company name"))
    city = forms.CharField(help_text=mark_safe('What county?'), label='locality')
    state = forms.CharField(help_text=mark_safe('Please enter the state'))
    zip = forms.IntegerField(help_text=mark_safe('Please enter a zip code.'))
    address = forms.CharField(help_text=mark_safe('Please enter an address.'))
    phone = forms.IntegerField(help_text=mark_safe('Please include country code.'), label='tele')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('company', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'address', 'phone', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

So this one works, but it is really impractical and concerning as I haven't solved the root issue.

*Screenshot of hardcoding result* (can't post because I don't have enough rep, but trust me everything works)

So that brings us to now, I've tried a few other things, but nothing has gotten me as close to what I want as hardcoding, so I need to figure out the underlying mistake I have made.

So here is what I am working with:

**models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

**forms.py** (current hardcoded version):

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(help_text=mark_safe("Please enter an appropriate human name."), label='human name')
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput, help_text=mark_safe('Which office?'), label='telegraph')
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, help_text=mark_safe('Something that doesnt look awful'),
                                label='Passcode')
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, help_text=mark_safe('Something else'), label='Passcode 2')
    company = forms.CharField(help_text=mark_safe("Please enter a company name"))
    city = forms.CharField(help_text=mark_safe('What county?'), label='locality')
    state = forms.CharField(help_text=mark_safe('Please enter the state'))
    zip = forms.IntegerField(help_text=mark_safe('Please enter a zip code.'))
    address = forms.CharField(help_text=mark_safe('Please enter an address.'))
    phone = forms.IntegerField(help_text=mark_safe('Please include country code.'), label='tele')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('company', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'address', 'phone', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

**views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from apps.dashboard.forms import SignUpForm

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()  # load the profile instance created by the signal
            user.profile.company = form.cleaned_data.get('company')
            user.profile.city = form.cleaned_data.get('city')
            user.profile.state = form.cleaned_data.get('state')
            user.profile.zip = form.cleaned_data.get('zip')
            user.profile.address = form.cleaned_data.get('address')
            user.profile.phone = form.cleaned_data.get('phone')
            user.save()
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect(main)
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

**template** (html):

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>
                    <form method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {% for field in form %}
                            <p>
                                {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
                                {{ field }}
                                {% if field.help_text %}
                                    <small style="color: grey">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
                                {% endif %}
                                {% for error in field.errors %}
                                    <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </p>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Rob Simpson's answer looks like the correct one to me. In any case it is the one that solved it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the OPs original concern about the help_text being escaped:

The 'safe' filter can be used, for example...

```
    {% if field.help_text %}
      <small style="color: grey">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</small>
    {% endif %}
```

gives the list you're looking for in the rendered template.

You might want to see the SO post entitled [Django template escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306669/django-template-escaping) for more examples of this behaviour and how to control it.

Comment: Looks like the right answer to me. Thanks a lot, that helped me too.

Comment: Thank you! If you think so then can you comment on OP? My rep is too low...

Comment: It looks like help_texts will only work for model fields like `username` and `email`. For other fields, you can set the `help_text` in the `__init__` method. Please look @alasdair answer for that

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `help_texts` will only work for model fields like `username` and `email`. For other fields, you can set the `help_text` in the `__init__` method.

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        ...
        help_texts = {
            'username': 'Please enter an appropriate human name.',
            'email': 'Which office?',
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password1'].help_text = 'Something that doesnt look awful'
        self.fields['password2'].help_text = 'Something else'
```

Instead of adding the profile fields to the `SignUpForm`, I would create a separate model form for profile

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        ...
```

Then include both forms in your view and template.

Comment: Why didn't you include the fields? Is this part of something larger? I get this error `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form SignUpForm needs updating.`

Comment: I left the fields out because they aren't directly related to the answer. You should include them in your form.

Comment: Excellent, so that works. So I have to do those one line at a time? One line for the label and one for the help_text? `self.fields['password1'].help_text = 'Something that doesnt look awful'
 self.fields['password1'].label = 'Passcode'`

Comment: Technically, you don't need a new line, since Python lets you do `a, b = 1, 2`, but that would be pretty unreadable. Set the label and help text on separate lines.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the `__init__` method before, but your approach works better. I appreciate it.

Comment: In `class Meta`, `help_texts = {'username': 'Please enter a username', 'email': 'Your email address will not be displayed publically'}` didn't work, but in __init__ worked. Any idea why ? Django 3.2

Comment: @anjanesh I can’t help in the comments. Please ask a new question and include your code. More people will see a new question so you’re more likely to get an answer.

Comment: It's your answer that led me to this in Google. "It looks like help_texts will only work for model fields like username and email. For other fields, you can set the help_text in the __init__ method." - In my case `help_texts` didnt work but `__init__` method did.

Comment: @anjanesh the docs say `help_texts` should work, so if it isn’t working for you, then you need to ask a new question and show your code. This question is 4 years old so I don’t think you’ll get help in the comments.