# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'

Tags: javascript, python, html

I get this error when I run my webapp. It says that the error is found here:

```
var rows = ({&#39;CurrentLocation&#39;: &#39;Norwich&#39;}, {&#39;CurrentLocation&#39;: &#39;Sheringham&#39;}, {&#39;CurrentLocation&#39;: &#39;Cambridge&#39;})
```

This is my code:

```
def search():
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute("SELECT CurrentLocation FROM driver WHERE OnJourney=0")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()  # data from database
    return render_template("Search.html", rows=rows)
```

```
var rows = {{ rows }}
       var row;
       var locations = [];
       for (row in rows) {
        locations.push(row['CurrentLocation']);
       }
       var location;
       for (location in locations) {
        var origin = location;
       }
```

Is there any way I can pass that dict from python to javascript without getting this error? Thanks for your help

Comment: Try replacing & characters in your first code sample with their corresponding character.(&#39;CurrentLocation&#39) Or not using them at all

Comment: `&#39` is `'` so i think you are double quoting your text somewhere

Comment: I get that text from python, I can't change the text, it's gotten from mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using Django templates.

If so, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11306935/204723) might help.

Basically, I think you want to turn off autoescaping, so:

```
{% autoescape off %}
var rows = {{ rows }}
{% endautoescape %}
```